# Move set of cells with some blanks so that set is right aligned

Tags: excel, move, vba

In Excel, I have a very big document with a lot of data and I am looking for the best way to move cells.

I have columns `A`, `B`, `C`,  and `D`, and I want to move them to `C`, `D`, `E`, and `F`. The problem is that now it is left-aligned, so sometimes there is nothing in the `D` cell so then it puts those values which should be in `D` in the `C` cell. What is the best way to resolve this?

There is a link to a picture about how I mean it:

[image: SO19227512 question example]

Comment: I can not understand your question.

Comment: try with macro recorder in Excel as a good starting point.

Comment: I tried to change the wording a bit to make more sense, does it still have your intended meaning @user2850497?

Comment: for example 
a column; number
b column; streetname
c column; streetname 2
d column; city

but where is not streetname 2 there is the city name in the C than. 
I want to put every city to the F.

Comment: I just can't understand. You have the sentence all mixed around

Comment: basicly move D cell to F cell. if D is empty than move C to F. now its more clear?

Comment: http://kepfeltoltes.hu/131007/excel_example_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.jpg
This is how I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim N As Long, L As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For L = 1 To N
        While Cells(L, "F") = ""
            Cells(L, 1).Insert (xlShiftToRight)
        Wend
    Next L
End Sub
```